# Codeigniter vs Elgg

Tags: codeigniter, elgg

I have been writing my site with Codeigniter for a while. My site has functions like a social networking site: login, make friends, comments, follow, post status, etc.

I just found out about Elgg, seems great so far.

I want to know, without knowing too much about Elgg, would you usually use it :

as a replacement of CI

or

a compliment to CI

I can rewrite the CI code into Elgg if really neccessary, of course, not something I would like to do.

Comment: @Alfonso, I said "without knowing too much about Elgg", that's why I asked if they are replacement or compliment. Don't answer if your answer isn't helpful.

Comment: I did not respond. I commented.

Answer (score 8):

[Elgg](http://elgg.org/) is meant to be the backbone of your site. It could be installed alongside Codeigniter, but there's no clear way to integrate them - it's similar to trying to use CI and WordPress together. You probably want to choose one or the other, they are not comparable.

- Elgg = Social Networking Engine
- Codeigniter = PHP Framework

Elgg is a full-blown solution, while Codeigniter is a means to write one yourself.